# what is wrong with my switch() and or my .on?

Tags: javascript, node.js

ignore the notes, and the mess, im super new and dont understand why the second function isn't doing what is expected. the first function runs just fine, its sets a prompt on the terminal and switches to function 2, this is my problem. it gets stuck in a perpetual loop that just prompts the user for input but the function never closes out to run the 3rd function. they are just copy pasted and a few key things have changed so im unsure of what is going wrong

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});


let mainMenu = {
    "Ribs": 8.99,
    "Chicken Sandwich": 10.99,
    "Pork Chop": 7.99,
    "Spaghetti": 7.99,
    "Caesar Salad": 6.99
};

let sideMenu ={
    'Side Salad': 3.99,
    'Fries': 2.99,
    'Mashed Potatoes': 2.99,   
    'BreadSticks': 1.99,
    'Corn on the Cob': 3.99
    
};




showMain();

function showMain() {
    console.log('Hi! welcome to bottega diner');
    console.log(` Entrees:
         ${JSON.stringify(mainMenu, undefined, 2)}`); //console.table?

        rl.setPrompt(`What can I start you off with?`);
        rl.prompt();
        rl.on('line', (choice1) => {
            switch (choice1) {
                case "ribs" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice1} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides();
                    break;
                case "chicken sandwich" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice1} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides();
                    break;
                case "pork chop" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice1} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides();
                    break;
                case "spaghetti" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice1} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides();
                    break;
                case "caesar salad" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice1} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides();
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('sorry we are out of that today')
                    rl.close();
                    break;                                    
            }
            
        });
};




function showSides() {
    console.log(` Side Dishes:
        ${JSON.stringify(sideMenu, undefined, 2)}`);//console.table

        rl.setPrompt(`You also get 2 side dishes with your order`);
        rl.prompt();
        rl.on('line', (choice2) => {
            switch (choice2) {
                case "side salad" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice2} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides2();
                    break;
                case "fries" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice2} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides2();
                    break;
                case "mashed potatoes" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice2} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides2();
                    break;
                case "bread sticks" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice2} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides2();
                    break;
                case "corn on the cob" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice2} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    showSides2();
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('sorry we are out of that today')
                    rl.close();
                    break;                                    
            }
    
        });
};

function showSides2() {
    console.log(` Side Dishes:
        ${JSON.stringify(sideMenu, undefined, 2)}`);//console.table

        rl.setPrompt(`And for your second side?`);
        rl.prompt();
        rl.on('line', (choice3) => {
            switch (choice3) {
                case "side salad" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice3} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    purchaseTotal();
                    break;
                case "fries" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice3} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    purchaseTotal();
                    break;
                case "mashed potatoes" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice3} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    purchaseTotal();
                    break;
                case "bread sticks" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice3} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    purchaseTotal();
                    break;
                case "corn on the cob" :
                    console.log(`OH!? The ${choice3} is a great option!`);//change this please FTLG
                    rl.close();
                    purchaseTotal();
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('sorry we are out of that today')
                    rl.close();
                    break;                                    
            }
        
        });
};
```

Comment: You're closing your readline interface with `r1.close()`, before attempting to use it in calls to `showSides` (and subsequently `showSides2`). That's your error -- you can't expect to use the interface in any meaningful capacity after closing it.

Comment: the showMain function works as expected, and brings up showSides function, so am i wrong to assume that the logic applied in showMain should apply in showSides? its my understanding that i am re   opening the prompt in showSides and showSides2

Comment: You are not wrong to assume that the same logic should apply to both -- but both of your functions, as it currently stands, contain a fault which prevents your program from behaving as you want it to, so your assumption is beside the point here. The fault has to do with your intent and execution of "closing" the `readline` interface (with calls to `r1.close`) before proceeding calling `showSides`. You should not be closing the interface (read: calling `r1.close`) before you are done prompting the user altogether.

Comment: I also recommend you delete your question after you've fixed things -- it's too narrow-scoped and isn't of much benefit to anyone else here, I'd wager, please take no offence. Good luck :)